# Как пишется частица НЕ в заданном предложении: недаром или не даром?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

***Не даром старинная мудрость гласит: "Ночью все кошки серы"***.

Хочу логически выделить наречие в начале предложения. Будет ли это ошибкой?

**Информация к вопросу**

1. Мне нужен был интересный вопрос про эту пару наречных выражений: ***недаром*** и ***не даром.***
2. **Теория там вроде бы простая.** Розенталь, [§ 61. Частица НЕ с наречиями](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81):

Пункт 6. Частица НЕ пишется слитно: <...>  2) в отыменных наречиях: невдалеке, невдомёк, невзначай, невмоготу, невмочь, невпопад, невтерпёж, **недаром (‘не напрасно’, но: не даром — ‘не бесплатно’)**, некстати, неспроста, нехотя (глагольного происхождения)...

3. В Нацкорпусе **частотность у "недаром" выше** (10200:940). Думаю, что это **влияние правила.** В действительности же эта пара не так проста и мало чем отличается от других парных вариантов, например: неинтересно/не интересно. **Зря эти слова попали в этот список.**
4. **Примеры**

Но алмазные слова и даются ***не даром.*** [И. Ф. Анненский. Вторая книга отражений (1909)]

***Не даром*** ведь говорится, что всё гениальное ― просто. [Письмо молодого человека подруге (2002)]

5. **А это стихи Есенина!**  **Хорошие!**

*О, привет тебе, зверь мой любимый!

**Ты не даром даешься ножу.**

Как и ты – я, отвсюду гонимый,

Средь железных врагов прохожу.*

*Как и ты – я всегда наготове.

И хоть слышу победный рожок,

Но отпробует вражеской крови

Мой последний, смертельный прыжок.*

*И пускай я на рыхлую выбель

Упаду и зароюсь в снегу…

Все же песню отмщенья за гибель

Пропоют мне на том берегу.*

[В книге Василия Шукшина. Калина красная (1973)]  (Текст **потом поправили.**)

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Спасибо!  Странные стихи, я их раньше не видела. Вы бы узнали Есенина по этим стихам? Вроде бы тема совсем не его (1921 год).  Почему все лучшее в нашей культуре непременно гибло, не достигнув своего расцвета. Вы можете объяснить это?

Comment: Нет, не узнал бы (я вообще сейчас не читаю стихов и не разбираюсь в них). Не думаю, что всё лучшее гибло. Что было способно, расцветало... Тема очень философическая, многогранная, запредельная и в то же время общечеловеческая, близкая. Не досуг мне об этом рассуждать. Просто жизнь любого человека, в том числе и гения, зависит от огромного множества факторов. И разве мало у нас достигнувших расцвета. Или я не так понял ваш посыл...

Comment: Что касается вопроса, я бы не стал писать раздельно "недаром" в вашем первом предложении и здесь тоже: *Не даром ведь говорится, что всё гениальное ― просто.*  Мне кажется, в этих случаях семантика не позволяет.  А вот с "алмазами" и со стихом всё нормально, раздельно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, хотя я не во всем согласна с вами. Вы вроде бы изменились, вы запомнились мне другим.  Но будем надеяться, что все меняется к лучшему, и духовный рост всегда связан с переменами. Спасибо еще раз за ваше внимание.

Comment: Ничё я не изменился – вы чё? :)  Я здесь поверхностен, обтекаем, компромиссен...  Но всё-таки: если вы хотите логически выделить – выделяйте (устно), вот только на письме (раздельно) это будет выглядеть, на мой глаз, несуразно. // Духовный рост – что-то я не совсем понимаю, о чём вы, простите, искренне... // А за вопрос, конечно, от меня, как всегда, отметка.

Comment: А эти стихи нравятся, поэта узнаете?  (Только сами догадайтесь.)  Море любит солнце, солнце любит море…
Волны заласкают ясное светило
И, любя, утопят, как мечту в амфоре...

Comment: Нет, не узнаю. Посмотрел, узнал. Мне сказки Пушкина нравятся.

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь два варианта, но больше хочется написать раздельно по аналогии с "не зря".

Comment: И про стихи что-нибудь скажите. Узнали поэтов, нравятся вам стихи?

Comment: Я не поклонник стихов, но и не противник. Что значит вторая строчка? Такие стихи часто надо расшифровывать, надо думать, а не всегда хочется напрягаться. Третий столбик не очень понятен, должна быть предыстория.